# Kubernetes: when Horizontal Autocaling happens, only Log from 1 pod is written & logs from 2 auto scaled pods are not printed

Tags: kubernetes, logging, jboss5.x, horizontal-scaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with max 4 pods and when there are more than 1 pods running, i see application server log in all the pods are exact replica, **Main issue is logs are written from one pod only, nothing is printed from other 2 Pods** (auto scaled one's)

Example:

My Application server is Jboss 5.1
When there are 3 pods, like Pod 1, Pod 2 & Pod 3
If i access jboss server log file through the terminal in each of these pod's, content of server.log file is exact replica in all 3 pods and **i am not able to find the logs from Pod 2 & Pod3**

Is there a config i need to update to print logs from all the pods with in the container (Note HPA is enabled to scale up to 4 pods)

**Below is my Deployment yaml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "32"
      creationTimestamp: "2022-04-06T07:02:40Z"
      generation: 149
      labels:
        customerid: 4000-sss-prod
        environment: prod
      managedFields:
      - apiVersion: apps/v1
        fieldsType: FieldsV1
        fieldsV1:
          f:spec:
            f:replicas: {}
        manager: vpa-recommender
        operation: Update
        subresource: scale
      - apiVersion: apps/v1
        fieldsType: FieldsV1
        fieldsV1:
          f:spec:
            f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
            f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
            f:selector: {}
            f:strategy:
              f:rollingUpdate:
                .: {}
                f:maxSurge: {}
                f:maxUnavailable: {}
              f:type: {}
            f:template:
              f:metadata:
                f:labels:
                  .: {}
                  f:app: {}
                  f:version: {}
              f:spec:
                f:containers:
                  k:{"name":"ecommerce"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:env:
                      .: {}
                      k:{"name":"JAVA_OPTS"}:
                        .: {}
                        f:name: {}
                      k:{"name":"JIRA_KEY"}:
                        .: {}
                        f:name: {}
                        f:value: {}
                      k:{"name":"SF_ACCOUNT_NUMBER"}:
                        .: {}
                        f:name: {}
                        f:value: {}
                    f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:ports:
                      .: {}
                      k:{"containerPort":9443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                        .: {}
                        f:containerPort: {}
                        f:protocol: {}
                    f:resources:
                      .: {}
                      f:limits: {}
                      f:requests: {}
                    f:securityContext:
                      .: {}
                      f:capabilities:
                        .: {}
                        f:add: {}
                      f:privileged: {}
                    f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                    f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                    f:volumeMounts:
                      .: {}
                      k:{"mountPath":"/var/persistent/"}:
                        .: {}
                        f:mountPath: {}
                        f:name: {}
                f:dnsPolicy: {}
                f:restartPolicy: {}
                f:schedulerName: {}
                f:securityContext: {}
                f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
                f:volumes:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"name":"XXXX3-persistent-pv"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:persistentVolumeClaim: {}
        manager: Go-http-client
        operation: Update
        time: "2022-04-06T07:02:40Z"
      - apiVersion: apps/v1
        fieldsType: FieldsV1
        fieldsV1:
          f:metadata:
            f:annotations: {}
          f:status:
            f:conditions:
              .: {}
              k:{"type":"Available"}:
                .: {}
                f:type: {}
              k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
                .: {}
                f:lastTransitionTime: {}
                f:status: {}
                f:type: {}
        manager: kube-controller-manager
        operation: Update
        time: "2022-06-25T06:11:17Z"
      - apiVersion: apps/v1
        fieldsType: FieldsV1
        fieldsV1:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:customerid: {}
              f:environment: {}
          f:spec:
            f:template:
              f:metadata:
                f:labels:
                  f:customerid: {}
                  f:environment: {}
              f:spec:
                f:containers:
                  k:{"name":"ecommerce"}:
                    f:env:
                      k:{"name":"JAVA_OPTS"}:
                        f:value: {}
                    f:image: {}
                    f:resources:
                      f:limits:
                        f:cpu: {}
                        f:memory: {}
                      f:requests:
                        f:cpu: {}
                        f:memory: {}
                f:nodeSelector: {}
                f:volumes:
                  k:{"name":"XXXX3-persistent-pv"}:
                    f:persistentVolumeClaim:
                      f:claimName: {}
        manager: GoogleCloudConsole
        operation: Update
        time: "2023-04-03T07:00:21Z"
      - apiVersion: apps/v1
        fieldsType: FieldsV1
        fieldsV1:
          f:metadata:
            f:annotations:
              f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
          f:status:
            f:availableReplicas: {}
            f:conditions:
              k:{"type":"Available"}:
                f:lastTransitionTime: {}
                f:lastUpdateTime: {}
                f:message: {}
                f:reason: {}
                f:status: {}
              k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
                f:lastUpdateTime: {}
                f:message: {}
                f:reason: {}
            f:observedGeneration: {}
            f:readyReplicas: {}
            f:replicas: {}
            f:updatedReplicas: {}
        manager: kube-controller-manager
        operation: Update
        subresource: status
        time: "2023-04-13T11:58:40Z"
      name: ecommerce
      namespace: 4000-sss-prod
      resourceVersion: "7896582563"
      uid: fghyytu-k258-4jb4-77z0-XXXXXXXXXXXX
    spec:
      progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
      replicas: 3
      revisionHistoryLimit: 10
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: ecommerce
          version: beta
      strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 1
          maxUnavailable: 0
        type: RollingUpdate
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            app: ecommerce
            customerid: 4000-sss-prod
            environment: prod
            version: beta
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: SF_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
              value: "4000"
            - name: JIRA_KEY
              value: sss-prod
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/persistent/auto-heap-dumps
                -Dxxx4.host.address=www.gosss.com -Dxxx4.db.connection=jdbc:oracle:thin:@4000db.xxxx.net:1521:stage
                -Dxxx4.db.user=DRY_RUN_BOND -Dxxx4.db.access.token=dry_run_bond -Djboss.server.log.dir=/var/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/logs/
            image: gcr.io/XXXXXXXXXXXX-core/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX_40
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: ecommerce
            ports:
            - containerPort: 9443
              protocol: TCP
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: "4"
                memory: 18Gi
              requests:
                cpu: "1"
                memory: 8Gi
            securityContext:
              capabilities:
                add:
                - SYS_ADMIN
              privileged: true
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/persistent/
              name: XXXX3-persistent-pv
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          nodeSelector:
            cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: stable-prod-e2
          restartPolicy: Always
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 150
          volumes:
          - name: XXXX3-persistent-pv
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: 4000-sss-fs
    status:
      availableReplicas: 3
      conditions:
      - lastTransitionTime: "2022-04-06T07:42:00Z"
        lastUpdateTime: "2023-04-03T06:58:35Z"
        message: ReplicaSet "ecommerce-7cd6dd596c" has successfully progressed.
        reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
        status: "True"
        type: Progressing
      - lastTransitionTime: "2023-04-13T11:58:40Z"
        lastUpdateTime: "2023-04-13T11:58:40Z"
        message: Deployment has minimum availability.
        reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
        status: "True"
        type: Available
      observedGeneration: 149
      readyReplicas: 3
      replicas: 3
      updatedReplicas: 3
```

Comment: Check the problem may be with the custom metrics setup, not with HPA. Please check if the SA used has the permissions. After ensuring that logging is enabled for the cluster and project, verify that the service account(s) associated with the problematic nodes have the following required [logging permissions](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/troubleshooting#write_permissions):
Check you may assign custom SAs to clusters or remove the default Editor permission from the default SA and in both cases neglect to re-add the necessary Logging and Monitoring roles to enable clust

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy
will check on the permission but a question:
 If there was permission issue with SA, it should not allow any of the pods to write to server log , correct me if i am wrong.
But 1 of the pod within the container is writing to server.log file in below path
/var/persistent/ecommerce/logs/

Comment: Your right@Warrior, Can you try to increase the **memory request and limit on the metrics server**. Because the metrics server watches all pods and nodes in the cluster, the memory usage can grow very high (metrics server may got OOMKilled) when there are a lot of changes (pods/nodes created/deleted) in the cluster at the same time. And also use the command **kubectl top pods** to get the more details.